# Display whole data to the Admin

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have one database it contains some user information column including with is Admin column.
My requirement is that the loggined user is an admin, then he has a right to see the first name and last name of the users that i stored in the database.
If i use select clause, it shows only the loggined person's information. But i want to display all the users information. How it will be work?

Comment: What kind of question is "How it will be work?"

Answer (score 1):

As Liao pointed out, it's very difficult to understand your question and even harder to provide a definitive answer due to the lack of technical information.  As a general pointer:

> If i use select clause, it shows only the loggined person's information

This implies you are running a query along the lines of SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = 'current user id' - i.e. you are restricting your query to a single record.  Pulling back all users would require the same query without the WHERE clause.

> loggined user is an admin, then he has a right

This depends on a) how you application currently handles security b) how the method in question gets access to information about the current user.  A very basic approach would be to assume you have access to an object representing the current user, and therefore can just do

`if (currentUser->IsAdmin == true) {`

As I re-read your question it sounds like either your are trying to hack an existing application to make it do more, or just have very little knowledge of writing applications (both from the low-level code point of view and from the higher "architecture" standing).